# Unable to print dataframe from the extracted Boolean values

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
diamonds = pd.read_csv('diam.csv')
print(diamonds.head())


Unnamed: 0  carat   cut color   clarity depth   table   price   x   y   z   quality?color
0   0   0.23    Ideal   E   SI2 61.5    55.0    326 3.95    3.98    2.43    Ideal,E
1   1   0.21    Premium E   SI1 59.8    61.0    326 3.89    3.84    2.31    Premium,E
2   2   0.23    Good    E   VS1 56.9    65.0    327 4.05    4.07    2.31    Good,E
3   3   0.29    Premium I   VS2 62.4    58.0    334 4.20    4.23    2.63    Premium,I
4   4   0.31    Good    J   SI2 63.3    58.0    335 4.34    4.35    2.75    Good,J
```

I want to print only the `object` data types

```
x=diamonds.dtypes=='object'
diamonds.where(diamonds[x]==True)
```

But I get this error:

```
unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

Comment: `where` uses the row axis. Use `diamonds.loc[:, diamonds.dtypes == 'object']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`where` uses the row axis. Use `diamonds.loc[:, diamonds.dtypes == object]`, or the builtin [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

From your post (badly formatted) I recreated the *diamonds* DataFrame,
getting result like below:

```
   Unnamed: 0  carat      cut color clarity  depth  table  price     x     y     z quality?color
0           0   0.23    Ideal     E     SI2   61.5   55.0    326  3.95  3.98  2.43     Ideal,E 1
1           1   0.21  Premium     E     SI1   59.8   61.0    326  3.89  3.84  2.31   Premium,E 2
2           2   0.23     Good     E     VS1   56.9   65.0    327  4.05  4.07  2.31      Good,E 3
3           3   0.29  Premium     I     VS2   62.4   58.0    334  4.20  4.23  2.63   Premium,I 4
4           4   0.31     Good     J     SI2   63.3   58.0    335  4.34  4.35  2.75        Good,J
```

When you run `x = diamonds.dtypes == 'object'` and print *x*, the result is:

```
Unnamed: 0       False
carat            False
cut               True
color             True
clarity           True
depth            False
table            False
price            False
x                False
y                False
z                False
quality?color     True
dtype: bool
```

It is a *bool* vector, containing answer to the question *is this column of object type*?

Note that `diamonds.columns.where(x).dropna().tolist()` prints:

```
['cut', 'color', 'clarity', 'quality?color']
```

i.e. names of columns with *object* type.

So to print all columns of *object* type you should run:

```
diamonds[diamonds.columns.where(x).dropna()]
```